# What technique is it when you use strings of another language in an English poem?

Tags: terminology

In Wilfred Owen's poem he ends with "Dulce et decorum est/Pro patria mori". I wonder if there is a recognised term to refer to this technique. Another example of its use is in T.S Eliot's "The Wasteland", where he has lines in German and French such as "And drank coffee, and talked for an hour. Bin gar keine Russin..."

Comment: There's a whole slew of [named tropes](http://rhetoric.byu.edu) that could apply. Enigma, cacozelia, graechismus... some are considered poor style. The exact one for using foreignisms in general (not just Greek or Hebrew) I couldn't find, but I'm sure it's in there.

Comment: In some cases, it's "pretension".

Comment: @RonJohn... exactly. :)

Comment: Are you looking for the word *macaronic*?  I would reserve that term for more equal mixes, e.g. a few of the Carmina Burana alternate a line in German with a line in Latin or Romance, or verses in one with a refrain in the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Plurilingualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurilingualism)** is switching between languages.

**[Heteroglossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroglossia)** is a more general term for the juxtaposition of different kinds or styles of speech and can refer to mixing high and low registers or dialects or languages. Bakhtin considered this a defining characteristic of some types of literature.

Answer (score 3):

**Code switching** is used to refer to this, even in poetry:

> In linguistics, code-switching or language alternation occurs when a speaker alternates between two or more languages, or language varieties, in the context of a single conversation or situation. — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)

For example:

- [Code-Switching in Bilingual Chicano Poetry](https://www.jstor.org/stable/340213)
- [Code-Switching in Poetry: “Crickets in Three Languages”](https://www.randianderson.com/code-switching-poetry/)
- [The function and significance of bilingual code-switching in English poetry with a special focus on the work of Eliot and Pound](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10131752.2011.574000?journalCode=racr20)

Answer (score 0):

Wilfred Owen's use of "Dulce et decorum est" is also an **allusion** to the *Odes* of Horace.

In *The Waste Land* the author T S Eliot **alludes** to Baudelaire's *Fleurs du Mal* with the line "*hypocrite lecteur!—mon semblable,—mon frère!*"

Frequently an allusion will be in the form of a direct quotation from another text.

Allusions are often in a language other than the language of the work in which they are found. Yet allusions are even-more-often written in the same language as the text in which the allusion is used.

Comment: Far too broad. As your last sentence concedes.

Comment: The two examples with which I led are both taken from the original question, and I have identified both accurately. The biggest problem with my answer is that it goes beyond the scope of the query.

Comment: This simply isn't the answer to the question. The answer to "What technique is it when you use strings of another language in an English poem?" is not "allusion."